# Can the name of a managed package be changed after it's released?

Tags: managed-package, isv

I know you can change package names when unmanaged, but what about managed ones after being released?  If I'm going to release a new version, can I give it a new name before the new release?  I'm talking about the name of the package itself, not the version name.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "Package Name" field of a "Managed - Released" package (see red arrow below) is editable and "Save" works (though I have not done an "Upload" after that).

So it appears the name can be changed after the package is released.

See James Loghry's **comment below** for more detail.

[image]

Released versions of this package:

[image]

Comment: Just to be clear, the namespace cannot be changed once it is set.  But the name and other attributes like the description, and even company information (gets pulled in when you deploy the package to other orgs) are editable.  In the company information scenario (and I think description and name as well), installed packages are smart enough to pick up the updated information without having to update nor reinstall the package.